# jQuery finding element by ID and if exists to remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a issue where I cant remove the error **msg** if it exists;

if you click in input and then out or if not valid email shows **error**, but click in and out again and repeats the error msg,

if the error exists I want to remove it and add again or if exists to not add again until valid? any ideas?

```js
function validEmail(v) {
  var r = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
  return (v.match(r) == null) ? false : true;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').blur(function() {

    var email = $(this).val();
    var emailError = "<p>The email address in the <b>E-mail</b> field is invalid.</p>";
    var emailInputId = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($("#" + emailInputId + "_error_message").length) {
      $("#" + emailInputId + "_error_message").remove();
    }
    console.log($(emailInputId + "_error_message"));
    if (validEmail(email)) {
      //alert('valid email');
      /*$.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
        method: 'post',
        data: {
          'email': email
        },
        caching: true
      });*/
      $(this).removeClass('cm-failed-field');
      $(this).prev().removeClass('cm-failed-label');
      $(this).next("span").remove();
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('cm-failed-field');
      $(this).prev().addClass('cm-failed-label');
      $(this).after("<span id=" + emailInputId + "_error_message' class='help-inline'><p>" + emailError + "</p></span>");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input x-autocompletetype="email" type="text" id="elm_32" name="user_data[email]" size="32" value="" class="ty-input-text cm-skip-avail-switch  cm-focus cm-failed-field">
```

Comment: Aren't you already doing that with `$(this).next("span").remove();`, no need to do it twice ?

Comment: And the snippet seems to work fine ?

Comment: well yea im trying but its not working hence why trying different things...

Comment: Did you try your code snippet, the message disappears as soon as a valid email is entered and the input loses focus

Comment: Snippet does not, click in it, click out, click in, click out... type fdsfds in and click out, enter valid email and click out it validates and removes error but the error is repeating each time its not valid which is the problem.

Comment: **TYPO**. `$(this).after("<span id=" + emailInputId + "_error_message' ...` ID attribute has no opening quote, so the ID value has a literal `'` at the end of it.

Comment: ahh well spotted, let me fix and see if then works, thanks mate will let you know

Comment: Works with the quote, **and** an additional check -> https://jsfiddle.net/6L3y2rpn/1/

Comment: @James just update changing 'emailInputId + "_error_message' `id`  to a  `class` will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the id (#) for class (.)

The Id in html document is an attribute to identify uniquely an element.

The Jquery, only get the first element when the selector is an id (#).

> ```
> if ($("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").length>0) {
>           $("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").remove();
>         }
>
>
>   $(this).after("<span class=" + emailInputId + "_error_message 
>                    help-inline' ><p>" + emailError + "</p></span>");
> ```

```js
function validEmail(v) {
  var r = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
  return (v.match(r) == null) ? false : true;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').blur(function() {

    var email = $(this).val();
    var emailError = "<p>The email address in the <b>E-mail</b> field is invalid.</p>";
    var emailInputId = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").length>0) {
      $("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").remove();
    }
    if (validEmail(email)) {
      //alert('valid email');
      /*$.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
        method: 'post',
        data: {
          'email': email
        },
        caching: true
      });*/
      $(this).removeClass('cm-failed-field');
      $(this).prev().removeClass('cm-failed-label');
      $(this).next("span").remove();
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('cm-failed-field');
      $(this).prev().addClass('cm-failed-label');
      $(this).after("<span class='" + emailInputId + "_error_message help-inline' ><p>" + emailError + "</p></span>");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input x-autocompletetype="email" type="text" id="elm_32" name="user_data[email]" size="32" value="" class="ty-input-text cm-skip-avail-switch  cm-focus cm-failed-field">
```